# Is there currently any way to implement Client Credentials Grant or an alternative with Zoho Creator API

Tags: zoho, raspberry-pi-pico

So im trying to implement a system where i want to create a POST request to a from of Zoho creator app using Zoho API directly from a Raspberry Pi Pico W, Basically its used to log certain events to Zoho form

The problem im facing is that Zoho API's OAuth does not support Client Credentials Grant so it's impossible to use API calls from a non-browser based application/client such as a pi pico to make requests without manually adding the Authorization code in the pico every 10 mins

P.S: I know very less about Zoho Creator and its API

Links: Zoho API Docs: https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2.1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OAuth for Non-Browser based applications](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/devices/client-protocol-flow.html) for generating tokens in your Pi device.

Steps:

- You can generate device code by a [Initiation request](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/devices/initiation-request.html) that will be similar to 'RYCH-0002'.
- Enter the code on [the verification page](https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v3/device) in a browser.
- When you poll for status in your Pi, it should give you the token.